# Weird Box Selection - Blender 4.0

Tags: outliner

I think there is a problem with the box selection in Blender 4.0. And What I Mean is the "Shortcut B Function" where in the older version of blender 3.6 i can press right mouse button to **Subtract Existing Selection**, But now whenever i press "B" and press right mouse button it just turn **Extend Existing Selection**.

Did i do something wrong? I dont want to click the tools and checklist the substract function everytime i want to unselect something with a box selection

[image]

Comment: I don't know about your Blender, but in my 3.6.4 and previous versions, I had to press the middle mouse button to subtract from existing selection... extending selection is automatically after pressing B and making a selection with left mouse button. Right button just cancels the action (just like in almost all other actions as well). Did you have a custom shortcut setup for your 3.6?

Comment: I believe this has changed in 4.0 although I've only briefly viewed the Blender YT video which I think explains the changes to selection mode [here](https://youtu.be/QhYplmY1gtU?t=264).

Comment: @JohnEason But the selections shown there are in _Vertex Paint_ mode... in _Object Mode_ and _Edit Mode_ for me the selection works in 4.0 as it did in the versions before, and there was no right button to subtract a selection. And the only tag under the question is "outliner", well in the _Outliner_ it works like in the _3D Viewport_. My problem with the question is, I see no change to previous versions and previous versions did not work as described in the question so I actually see no issue here.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Just checked the video again and you're correct about it only applying to vertex paint mode. He says it "applies across all modes" which I assumed meant across **all** modes not just in Vertex Paint.   I Box-deselect from a previous selection in Edit mode by holding down Ctrl by the way, not using MMB. That's the same in 4.0 so no change there.

Comment: @JohnEason Holding `Ctrl` to deselect is when immediately dragging a box selection without enabling box selection by pressing `B` beforehand as mentioned in the question. The tool enabled with `B` is a bit different. First of all it adds to an existing selection without the need to hold `Shift`(as you have to when simply dragging with the mouse) and subtracting from a selection is `MMB`. But anyways, both tools are working like they did in older versions, so I can only assume Adit had a custom shortcut setup or something like emulate 3-button mouse enabled... I cannot reproduce any issue.

Comment: Fair enough. I have the Box select option enabled most of the time here so never use the B key method. I just use the Shift key to add to a box selection.